# Why is ignite failing to deserialize a GridClosureProcessor object?

Tags: ignite

I know a similar  stack has been posted by others. My question is "it looks like Ignite is trying to deserialize a GridClosureProcessor (or a closure from it?) . If so, why is it doing that? I am trying to root cause this issue but none of my code is in the stack except MyCallable mentioned at the top (not actually in the stack).

No cache puts are happening in this code path unless they are internal. I mention this because of a comment on another post that "Unknown pair" can be caused by a cache put of the wrong type.

I am focusing on

> Failed to deserialize object
>   [typeName=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.closure.GridClosureProcessor$C2]

Here's the rest.

> [2019-04-08 22:20:23,724][ERROR][pub-#63][GridJobWorker] Failed to
>   initialize job
>   [jobId=800890ff961-7ff6a786-9d4d-43d8-91a0-70225c5e3a4a,
>   ses=GridJobSessionImpl [ses=GridTaskSessionImpl
>   [taskName=com.obfucorp.aa.project.core.jobs.MyCallable,
>   dep=GridDeployment [ts=1554761996013, depMode=SHARED,
>   clsLdr=sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@764c12b6,
>   clsLdrId=730290ff961-8d93b961-09f2-48c3-bd2f-49db31aae61e, userVer=0,
>   loc=true,
>   sampleClsName=o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor$RemovedItemsCleanupTask$1,
>   pendingUndeploy=false, undeployed=false, usage=1],
>   taskClsName=com.obfucorp.aa.project.core.jobs.MyCallable,
>   sesId=700890ff961-7ff6a786-9d4d-43d8-91a0-70225c5e3a4a,
>   startTime=1554762023663, endTime=9223372036854775807,
>   taskNodeId=7ff6a786-9d4d-43d8-91a0-70225c5e3a4a,
>   clsLdr=sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@764c12b6, closed=false,
>   cpSpi=null, failSpi=null, loadSpi=null, usage=1, fullSup=false,
>   internal=false, topPred=null,
>   subjId=7ff6a786-9d4d-43d8-91a0-70225c5e3a4a, mapFut=IgniteFuture
>   [orig=GridFutureAdapter [ignoreInterrupts=false, state=INIT, res=null,
>   hash=314803578]], execName=null],
>   jobId=800890ff961-7ff6a786-9d4d-43d8-91a0-70225c5e3a4a]] class
>   org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to deserialize object
>   [typeName=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.closure.GridClosureProcessor$C2]
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.unmarshal(IgniteUtils.java:9908)
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobWorker.initialize(GridJobWorker.java:438)
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobProcessor.processJobExecuteRequest(GridJobProcessor.java:1117)
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobProcessor$JobExecutionListener.onMessage(GridJobProcessor.java:1921)
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.invokeListener(GridIoManager.java:1555)
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.processRegularMessage0(GridIoManager.java:1183)
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.access$4200(GridIoManager.java:126)
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager$9.run(GridIoManager.java:1090)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: class
>   org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryObjectException: Failed to deserialize
>   object
>   [typeName=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.closure.GridClosureProcessor$C2]
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryClassDescriptor.read(BinaryClassDescriptor.java:875)
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize0(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1762)
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1714)
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.GridBinaryMarshaller.deserialize(GridBinaryMarshaller.java:310)
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryMarshaller.unmarshal0(BinaryMarshaller.java:99)
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.marshaller.AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.unmarshal(AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.java:82)
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.unmarshal(IgniteUtils.java:9902)
>     ... 10 more Caused by: class
>   org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryInvalidTypeException: Unknown pair
>   [platformId=0, typeId=-1409390795]    at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryContext.descriptorForTypeId(BinaryContext.java:696)
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize0(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1755)
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1714)
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryUtils.doReadObject(BinaryUtils.java:1799)
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.readObject(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1329)
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.closure.GridClosureProcessor$C2.readBinary(GridClosureProcessor.java:1872)
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryClassDescriptor.read(BinaryClassDescriptor.java:834)
>     ... 16 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Unknown pair
>   [platformId=0, typeId=-1409390795]    at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.MarshallerContextImpl.getClassName(MarshallerContextImpl.java:385)
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.MarshallerContextImpl.getClass(MarshallerContextImpl.java:335)
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryContext.descriptorForTypeId(BinaryContext.java:687)
>     ... 22 more

update - wanted to note this is happening a fresh deployment. There are no old files or persisted anything around. All classes are either pulled from even or freshly compiled. ty.

Pavel, here is the (Scala) code (redacted)

```
object MyCallable {
    type FooList = Array[Foo]
}

class MyCallable(cacheName: String) extends IgniteCallable[FooList] with Serializable with LazyLogging {
    @IgniteInstanceResource
    private var ignite: Ignite = _

    override def call(): FooList = {
        logger.debug("callable called.");
        val fooCache = ignite.getOrCreateCache[String, Foo](cacheName)
        val qry = new ScanQuery[String, Foo]()
        qry.setLocal(true)
        val cursor = fooCache.query(qry)
        val ret = cursor.iterator().asScala.map(e => e.getValue).toArray
        logger.info("load status array: {}", ret.mkString)
        return ret
    }

    @IgniteInstanceResource
    def setIgnite(ignite: Ignite): Unit = {
        this.ignite = ignite
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the com.obfucorp.aa.project.core.jobs.MyCallable class

Comment: Edited post to add code for class.

Answer (score 1):

`Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryInvalidTypeException: Unknown pair [platformId=0, typeId=-1409390795]`

Seems like you have lost your marshaller cache (`marshaller/` dir).

You can do `ignite.marshaller().marshal(new WhateverTypeIsCausingThis());` once to make this error go away.

Comment: I cannot see that method on ignite so I did this.

    val gkc: GridKernalContext = (ignite.asInstanceOf[IgniteKernal]).context()
    val marshaller = gkc.grid().configuration().getMarshaller

but, it did not help. I am not sure which type is causing this actually. It's not evident in the stack unless it's"org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.closure.GridClosureProcessor$C2]".

Comment: I looked on the server node. The directory is there and only contains /var/lib/ignite/work/marshaller/902610168.classname0. The contents of this single file is a string, "javax.cache.integration.CacheLoaderException". Is that expected?

(At this point in the code we have not loaded any caches yet.)

Does that mean anything?

Comment: Do you have persistence on? If the answer is yes, this means you have lost your marshaller cache. You should always keey work/marshaller alongside persistent data.

Comment: Yes, we do have persistence on. We get this error right after spinning up everything new (so nothing was actually persisted before startup). questions:
(1) How might we have lost the marshaller cache at that point (so early)?

(2) Do we need to create it explicitly on startup? I'm not sure it was ever there.

(3) what do I need to do to keep the work/marshaller alongside the persistent data as you say. I don't know what action to take on that.

Comment: I guess that you had leftover data (but not marshaller cache) from previous runs and Ignite did not know what types in this data map to.

Comment: Each run of the test wipes the data drives. Where else might it be looking?

Comment: Maybe this is because you query cache before even putting anything of that type. Try to put something first.